# In FL, can clients train different model architectures?

Tags: tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I practice on this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification), I would like that each client train a different architecture and different model, Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

TFF does support different clients having different model architectures.

However, the [Federated Learning for Image Classification tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/tutorials/federated_learning_for_image_classification) uses [`tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/build_federated_averaging_process) which implements the Federated Averaging ([McMahan et. al 2017](https://arxiv.org/abs/1602.05629)) algorithm, defined as each client receiving the same architecture. This is accomplished in TFF by "mapping" (in the functional programming sense) the model to each client dataset to produce a new model, and then aggregating the result.

To achieve different clients having different architectures, a different federated learning algorithm would need to be implemented. There are couple (non-exhaustive) ways this could be expressed:

1. Implement an alternative to [`ClientFedAvg`](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/610843c724740e1b041837cc93501b609fb05d8f/tensorflow_federated/python/learning/federated_averaging.py#L43). This method applies a fixed model to the clients dataset. An alternate implementation could potentially create a different architecture per client.
2. Create a replacement for `tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process`
   that uses a different function signature, splitting out groups of clients
   that would receive different architectures. For example, currently FedAvg
   looks like:

   ```
   (<state@SERVER, data@CLIENTS> → <state@SERVER, metrics@SERVER>
   ```

   this could be replaced with a method with signature:

   ```
   (<state@SERVER, data1@CLIENTS, data2@CLIENTS, ...> → <state@SERVER, metrics@SERVER>
   ```

   This would allow the function to internally `tff.federated_map()` different model architectures to different client datasets. This would likely only be useful in FL simulations or experimentation and research.

**However**, in federated learning there will be difficult questions around how to aggregate the models back on the server into a single global model. This probably needs to be designed out first.